# ReactJS - App Issues after Deployment

Tags: api, reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, react-scripts

I just started my first website with reactjs.

**Question 1**
On localhost I run my backend on `PORT=3001` and my app on `PORT=3000`.
Using `react-scripts build` I created the build for the frontend, but it looks like the `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` is not taken under consideration when creating the build.

Now after deployment on the server the api calls are always returning 404 as they never go to port 3001.

How can I pass the proxy with the build?

**Question 2**
On my local machine I run `react-scripts start` so i can directly access 
`http://localhost:3000/login`, but on the server I would always have to start with `http://example.com/` and then use the navigation to get to the login.

How can I better handle the urls?

Thank you,
Vanessa

Comment: can you share any server code?

Comment: @wnamen all my code is available here: https://github.com/n3ssi3/liveaboard-express

Comment: The server is here: http://new.tulamben.com/